# Unit Testing Destructive Methods

Tags: unit-testing

When doing unit tests on models, and database-altering methods/functions, what is the best methodology or mindset for unit testing? For instance, a "publish" function in a model has no test-able behaviors except for pass/fail, and in the case of passing, it modifies the database. Best practice or approach?

Current thoughts would be to create a mirror of the current database before testing, and just change the database selection in my unit test file. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You have to set up a testing database within your unit tests.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do unit test (=test in isolation):

- the business logic would execute against a fake database (Repository mock)
- the test checks if business logic has really called repository-delete method.

If you want an integration test with the business logic and the database you can

- open a database transaction
- add data to database via sql
- execute the business logic that destroys the data just added
- verify that data is not in database any more (via sql)
- rollback the database transaction.

Update:

If you are using .NET you should have a look at [ndbunit](http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) for java [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org)

Answer (score 1):

Use [xtunit](http://osherove.com/blog/2004/10/5/introducing-xtunit-an-unofficial-unit-testing-extensibility.html) if you are on .net. This will wrap your test in a transaction and roll it back when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mirror the database... stub it. If you are testing against a database, You are not unittesting.